# Is there any way to add a requestedPrivileges in manifest when using a UWP manifest app?

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, manifest

I've researched a lot on UWP manifest and previous versions security (in order to allow the UAC to pop up on apps), and for Windows platforms **pre-UWP** its true that you can add :

```
 <security> 
  <requestedPrivileges> 
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" 
     uiAccess="false"/> 
  </requestedPrivileges> 
</security>
```

on application manifest.
However for UWP apps, manifest apparently doesn't allow you to do this.

Do anyone have tried, and succeded on doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP apps shouldnt need the admin permissions. Can you tell bit more about your sceanrio?

Comment: Sure. Trying to do an app, which, comunicating in app2app , can update one of them. For this, i am not intending to use the Windows Store by any means, i want to control that. So, i use a MVP xamarin blog to do a similar idea, however my app keep poping with "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" which , for what i have researched , is because of the lack of privileges. On previous windows apps, this can be solved by invoking the UAC, together with other stuff.

Comment: is this helping? https://matthijs.hoekstraonline.net/2016/09/27/auto-updater-for-my-side-loaded-uwp-apps/

Comment: Dave, thanks for the quick reply. That's where i am getting the code :). Guess i could simply ask the guy if this is a problem on his side also (although he didnt mention anything). Didn't explore that option before. Will do now. Thanks.